# Centering a UILabel in a UITextView using NSLayoutConstraints

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm attempting to add a `UILabel` to a `UITextView` and have it centered at the top of the textView. Instead of it being centered, it's placed on the left. I suspect this is because the label's intrinsic size takes precedence over the constraint's attempt to stretch it across the view. Not sure how to address the issue though. Here's the code:

```
self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.titleLabel.text = @"Some text that should be centered in the textView";
[self addSubview:self.titleLabel];

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_titleLabel);

NSArray *hConstraint = 
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_titleLabel]-|"
                                               options:0 metrics:nil
                                                 views:viewsDictionary];
[self addConstraints:hConstraint];

NSArray *vConstraint = 
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(-50)-[_titleLabel]"
                                               options:0 metrics:nil
                                                 views:viewsDictionary];
[self addConstraints:vConstraint];
```

Here's a snippet from the iPad simulator of how the label is left justified:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `constraintsWithVisualFormat` to create centering constraints. You have to set the view's *center* to a certain position / relation, and the `constraintsWithVisualFormat` string syntax won't let you do that. You have to use `constraintWithItem:attribute:...` (or set it up in the nib/storyboard).

Here's code that centers one view in another horizontally:

```
NSLayoutConstraint* con =
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
  relatedBy:0
  toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
  multiplier:1 constant:0];
[superview addConstraint:con];
```

To set up a subview as centered in the nib, use the Editor menu to center it horizontally or vertically in its superview and then get rid of any superfluous constraints left over (if any - the nib editor is usually pretty good about getting rid of these automatically when you center something).

Oh, sorry, one more thing: one of the wonderful things about constraints is that you can constrain to *any* other view. The label may be in *front* of the text view, but that doesn't mean it has to be constrained to the text view. It can if you want, but then it will scroll with the text view, I think.

That should get you started. Lots more in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout

Comment: Thanks Matt. One question though -- wouldn't the layout relation be NSLayoutRelationEqual rather than 0?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I see that the NSLayoutRelation enum assigns 0 to NSLayoutRelationEqual, so they are the same.

Comment: Yeah, I discuss this in my book. You say `NSLayoutRelationEqual` so often, you might as well say `0` instead. It's just a time-saver.

Comment: A time saver? Just because NSLayoutRelationEqual == 0 right now, doesn't mean that will always be true.

Comment: It is easier to understand/read `NSLayoutRelationEqual` than `0`